# fixing sharp looking geometry objects with widthSegmentCount property

Tags: ios, geometry, blender, scenekit

Is it possible to assign **widthSegmentCount** (or height or chamfer) to a custom geometry object created in Blender. My geometry is rather sharp looking when imported to SceneKit. It looks great in Blender though. The sharpness is depicted in pictures.

[image]

[image]

The object is moving so setting **enableJittering** to true doesn't help.

I tried using this code since my object is basically a box:

```
let box = boxNode.geometry as! SCNBox
box.widthSegmentCount = 150
box.heightSegmentCount = 150
box.chamferSegmentCount = 150
```

and I'm getting an error: **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

Is this the best SceneKit can do or do I need to export my object from Blender  differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the quality of your mesh. You are just seeing individual pixels without smoothing.
`SCNView` exposes the `antialiasingMode` property that will help you get smoother edges (try `.Multisampling2X` or `.Multisampling4X`).

Comment: great, it does what I asked. However, it is reaaaly performance costly.